# How to add child entity for existing parent entity using spring data JPA?

Tags: java, spring-data-jpa, hibernate-mapping

I am totally new to Spring data JPA and hibernate.What i am trying to  is creating OneToOne to relation between two entity's shown below.

```
 @Entity
    public class Student {
    
        @Id
        @GeneratedValue
        private int id;
        private String name;
    
        @OneToOne
        @JoinColumn(name="id")
        private Passport passport;
    
        public Student() {
        }
    
    }
```

**And Second:-**

```
@Entity
public class Passport {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private  int id;
    private String number;

    public Passport() {
    }

    public Passport(int id, String number) {
        this.id = id;
        this.number = number;
    }
}
```

After running the program i inserted some dummy values to student and passport table and call the following function from CommandLineRunner to update specific student with passport.

```
 public void SaveStudentPassword(int student_id, Passport passport){
        Student student = entityManager.find(Student.class,student_id);
        logger.info("Details of student  -> {}",student);
        student.setPassport(passport);
        entityManager.persist(student);
        entityManager.flush();
    }
```

**Main Class implementing Command LineRunner:-**

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class DemoApplication implements  CommandLineRunner{

    @Autowired
    private StudentRepository studentRepository;
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(DemoApplication.class, args);
    }

    @Override
    public void run(String... args) throws Exception {
 
        studentRepository.SaveStudentPassword(1,new Passport(6,"pass151020"));
    }
}
```

Bellow is Exception What i get:-

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to execute CommandLineRunner
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.callRunner(SpringApplication.java:798) ~[spring-boot-2.3.3.RELEASE.jar:2.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.callRunners(SpringApplication.java:779) ~[spring-boot-2.3.3.RELEASE.jar:2.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:322) ~[spring-boot-2.3.3.RELEASE.jar:2.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1237) ~[spring-boot-2.3.3.RELEASE.jar:2.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1226) ~[spring-boot-2.3.3.RELEASE.jar:2.3.3.RELEASE]
    at com.example.demo.DemoApplication.main(DemoApplication.java:26) ~[classes/:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartLauncher.run(RestartLauncher.java:49) ~[spring-boot-devtools-2.3.3.RELEASE.jar:2.3.3.RELEASE]
Caused by: org.springframework.dao.DataIntegrityViolationException: could not execute statement; SQL [n/a]; constraint [null]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could not execute statement
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.convertHibernateAccessException(HibernateJpaDialect.java:298) ~[spring-orm-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.translateExceptionIfPossible(HibernateJpaDialect.java:255) ~[spring-orm-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.translateExceptionIfPossible(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:528) ~[spring-orm-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.dao.support.ChainedPersistenceExceptionTranslator.translateExceptionIfPossible(ChainedPersistenceExceptionTranslator.java:61) ~[spring-tx-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.dao.support.DataAccessUtils.translateIfNecessary(DataAccessUtils.java:242) ~[spring-tx-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:153) ~[spring-tx-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:749) ~[spring-aop-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:367) ~[spring-tx-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:118) ~[spring-tx-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:749) ~[spring-aop-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:691) ~[spring-aop-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at com.example.demo.Repository.StudentRepository$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$ef432965.SaveStudentPassword(<generated>) ~[classes/:na]
    at com.example.demo.DemoApplication.run(DemoApplication.java:36) ~[classes/:na]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.callRunner(SpringApplication.java:795) ~[spring-boot-2.3.3.RELEASE.jar:2.3.3.RELEASE]
    ... 10 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could not execute statement
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.SQLExceptionTypeDelegate.convert(SQLExceptionTypeDelegate.java:59) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.20.Final.jar:5.4.20.Final]
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:42) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.20.Final.jar:5.4.20.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:113) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.20.Final.jar:5.4.20.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:99) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.20.Final.jar:5.4.20.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.executeUpdate(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:200) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.20.Final.jar:5.4.20.Final]
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.update(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3450) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.20.Final.jar:5.4.20.Final]
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.updateOrInsert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3312) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.20.Final.jar:5.4.20.Final]
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.update(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3726) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.20.Final.jar:5.4.20.Final]
    at org.hibernate.action.internal.EntityUpdateAction.execute(EntityUpdateAction.java:201) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.20.Final.jar:5.4.20.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:604) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.20.Final.jar:5.4.20.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.lambda$executeActions$1(ActionQueue.java:478) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.20.Final.jar:5.4.20.Final]
    at java.base/java.util.LinkedHashMap.forEach(LinkedHashMap.java:723) ~[na:na]
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:475) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.20.Final.jar:5.4.20.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractFlushingEventListener.performExecutions(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:348) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.20.Final.jar:5.4.20.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultFlushEventListener.onFlush(DefaultFlushEventListener.java:40) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.20.Final.jar:5.4.20.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.service.internal.EventListenerGroupImpl.fireEventOnEachListener(EventListenerGroupImpl.java:102) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.20.Final.jar:5.4.20.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.doFlush(SessionImpl.java:1363) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.20.Final.jar:5.4.20.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.flush(SessionImpl.java:1350) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.20.Final.jar:5.4.20.Final]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator$SharedEntityManagerInvocationHandler.invoke(SharedEntityManagerCreator.java:314) ~[spring-orm-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy61.flush(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at com.example.demo.Repository.StudentRepository.SaveStudentPassword(StudentRepository.java:27) ~[classes/:na]
    at com.example.demo.Repository.StudentRepository$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$f105aebb.invoke(<generated>) ~[classes/:na]
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:218) ~[spring-core-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:771) ~[spring-aop-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:163) ~[spring-aop-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:749) ~[spring-aop-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:139) ~[spring-tx-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    ... 20 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.sql.SQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`testdb`.`student`, CONSTRAINT `FK6i2dofwfuu97njtfprqv68pib` FOREIGN KEY (`passport_id`) REFERENCES `passport` (`id`))
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:117) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.21.jar:8.0.21]
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:97) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.21.jar:8.0.21]
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLExceptionsMapping.translateException(SQLExceptionsMapping.java:122) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.21.jar:8.0.21]
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ClientPreparedStatement.executeInternal(ClientPreparedStatement.java:953) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.21.jar:8.0.21]
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ClientPreparedStatement.executeUpdateInternal(ClientPreparedStatement.java:1092) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.21.jar:8.0.21]
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ClientPreparedStatement.executeUpdateInternal(ClientPreparedStatement.java:1040) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.21.jar:8.0.21]
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ClientPreparedStatement.executeLargeUpdate(ClientPreparedStatement.java:1347) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.21.jar:8.0.21]
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ClientPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(ClientPreparedStatement.java:1025) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.21.jar:8.0.21]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.ProxyPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(ProxyPreparedStatement.java:61) ~[HikariCP-3.4.5.jar:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariProxyPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(HikariProxyPreparedStatement.java) ~[HikariCP-3.4.5.jar:na]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.executeUpdate(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:197) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.20.Final.jar:5.4.20.Final]
    ... 46 common frames omitted
```

Comment: You need to define the [`@JoinColumn`](https://www.baeldung.com/jpa-join-column) on the `@OneToOne` relation. Otherwise, JPA does not know how to join the tables and how to map the entity from a foreign key constrained colum.

Comment: Why are you using `@OneToMany`all of the sudden? What do you mean by "is not updated"? Your comment is quite unclear.

Comment: @Turing85 I am not using `@OneToMany` if u see in User class i am using `@OneToOne`.

Comment: "*@Turing85 thanks i added @OneToMany(name="id") in student class*" - "*@Turing85 I am not using @OneToMany*" -- So what is it now? Is the code in the post still up-to-date? --- "*if u see in User class*" - You did not provide a `User` class.

Comment: @Turing85 please pardon its my mistek i made a typing mistek,its Student not User and i added `@JoinColumn` in Student Class as you said and as a result every thing works fine but student with id=1 is not updated. `is not updated` mean first i created Student and passport entity and inserted some dummy value into it.And then i am implementing `OneToOne` relation between them.

Comment: It is still unclear what you mean by "student is not updated". Do you mean that the relation is not saved? The passport is not saved automatically, you have either to define the cascade behaviour on `Student`'s `@OneToOne`-relation or persist the passport before (re-)persisting the student. In the current state, I would expect a foreign key violation if the database is set up properly.

Comment: @Turing85 that is., i am trying to add passport for existing Student i am not creating student and passport at once.

Comment: @Turing85 exactly `relation ship is not saved`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on an error from log its looks like you need to join using `passport_id`

```
Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`testdb`.`student`, CONSTRAINT `FK6i2dofwfuu97njtfprqv68pib` FOREIGN KEY (`passport_id`) REFERENCES `passport` (`id`))
```

I believe you need to join `Student` and `Passport` as shown belwo
`@JoinColumn(name = "passport_id", referencedColumnName = "id", nullable = true)`

Mapped in the entity as below

```
@Entity
public class Student {
    
        @Id
        @GeneratedValue
        private int id;
        private String name;
    
        @OneToOne
        @JoinColumn(name = "passport_id", referencedColumnName = "id", nullable = true)
        private Passport passport;
    
        public Student() {
        }    
}
```